# Perl hash function mismanagement

Tags: perl

I am really struggling with this one. I am failing at understanding the mapping in the hash below. Let's use dummy data:

```
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
Adobe        Version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
```

The above can be in any unsorted order (Devicename is not used as I require the count only). I need to sort this and write them to a file.

```
$count_app{$AppName}{$Ver}{$Stat}++;

foreach $App (sort keys %count_app) {
  $app_counts = $count_app{$App};
  foreach $Rating (sort keys %$app_counts) {
    $status_counts = $app_counts->{$Rating};
    foreach $Status (sort keys %$status_counts) {
      $count = $status_counts->{$Status};

      print "$Rating $App $Status and $count\n";
    }
  }
}
```

The above is only the hash function, The rest of the code is not really needed here, but currently this will print the data sorted as expected. Problem is, I want to print it so it is Unique per Status. For instance:

```
Active:
     Adobe Version2 1
     Adobe Version3 3
     MS Office Version2 2
Obsolete
     Adobe Version1 1
     MS Office Version1 3
```

So sorting is important but so is separation. I have however tried many ways, but most either give me syntax errors, or when using `%seen` it will only use an app once but then skip the other relevant versions of the app.

Comment: Can't you just use the status as your first key instead of the app name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the status is most important to you, then just make that the key in the first level hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %app;

# Read data
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($name, $ver, $status) = unpack('A13A12A12');

  $app{$status}{$name}{$ver}++;
}

# Display data
for my $st (sort keys %app) {
  say "$st:";
  for my $nm (sort keys %{$app{$st}}) {
    for my $vr (sort keys %{$app{$st}{$nm}}) {
      say "\t$nm $vr $app{$st}{$nm}{$vr}";
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
Adobe        Version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
```

The output this generates is:

```
Active:
    Adobe Version2 1
    Adobe Version3 3
    MS Office version2 2
Obsolete:
    Adobe Version1 1
    MS Office Version1 3
```

But if you're going to want to generate different types of reports from this data, then I really recommend putting the data into a database table.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: If the data is in a database, then extract the data you need with SQL like `SELECT status, name, version, count(*) FROM applications GROUP BY status, name, version`.

Comment: @Gerry: It's a really simple fix to get to your (new) required output. Why not see if you can work it out yourself. It's a good test of how well you understand my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perl's function [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) are quite useful for this. `map` iterates over a list and `grep` filters a list.

Try something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my @table = ();

while (<DATA>)
{
  chomp;
  my $row = [split /  +/];
  push @table, $row;
}

my @status = uniq map { ${$_}[2] } @table;

for my $s (@status)
{
  print "$s:\n";

  my @subset = map { [${$_}[0], ${$_}[1]] } grep { ${$_}[2] eq $s } @table;
  my @products = uniq map { ${$_}[0] } @subset;

  for my $p (@products)
  {
    print "  $p:\n";
    my @versions = map { ${$_}[1] } grep { ${$_}[0] eq $p } @subset;

    for my $v (uniq @versions)
    {
      my $count = grep { $_ eq $v } @versions;
      print "    $v: $count\n";
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
Adobe        Version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
MS Office    Version1    Obsolete    devicename
MS Office    version2    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
Adobe        Version3    Active      devicename
```

It generates the following output:

```
Obsolete:
  MS Office:
    Version1: 3
  Adobe:
    Version1: 1
Active:
  MS Office:
    version2: 2
  Adobe:
    Version2: 1
    Version3: 3
```